# Convert multi table sql join with derived table to Linq

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have a working SQL query as shown below. I want to create an equivalent Linq query. Not have much success.

```
select u.Id as userId, u.CustomerId, a.Id as appId, a.Created as appCreated
from EO_AppUsers u
left join EO_Policies p on (u.Id = p.AppUser_Id)
CROSS APPLY (
    select TOP 1 id, created, AppUser_Id
    from EO_Applications d
    WHERE d.AppUser_id = u.id
    order by Created desc ) a 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EO_AppUsers] (
[Id] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EO_Policies] (
[Id] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[AppUser_Id] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EO_Applications] (
[Id] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[Created] DATETIME2 (7) NOT NULL,
[AppUser_Id] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
```

`EO_AppUsers` has a `EO_Policie`s and zero or more `EO_Applications`.

The SQL creates a report of all `EO_AppUsers` and associated `EO_Policies` and the latest/newest `EO_Applications`

The following handles returning EO_AppUsers and EO_Policies but is missing the EO_Applications. It needs the `CROSS APPLY` from the SQL query above.

```
        var q = (from u in dbContext.EO_AppUsers
                 join p in dbContext.EO_Policies on u.Id equals p.AppUser.Id
                 //join a in dbContext.EO_Applications on u.Id equals a.AppUser.Id
                 select new 
                 {
                    /// return fields from EO_AppUsers, EO_Policies and EO_Applications 
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this linq query.

```
from u in EO_AppUsers
join p in EO_Policies on u.Id equals p.AppUser_Id into pl
from lp in pl.DefaultIfEmpty()  
from a in EO_Applications.Where(d => d.AppUser_Id == u.Id)
                             .OrderByDescending(d => d.Created)
                             .Take(1)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty() 
select new { userId = u.Id,
             u.CustomerId,
             appId = a.Id,
             appCreated = a.Created,
             polId = lp.Id
            }
```

Comment: I had to change to OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY as I need EO_AppUsers & EO_Policies even if there is no EO_Applications for the EO_AppUsers .  Your linq query does not return any rows. I think  it is related. A left join is required. What would the linq query look like for a OUTER APPLY?

Comment: I added `DefaultIfEmpty()` for make it `OUTER APPLY`. Could you try again?